# Create a property of same name for sub-instance while parent property's writable is false

Tags: javascript

```js
"use strict";
var a = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    name: {
        writable: false,
        value: 'foo'
    }
});

var b = Object.create(a);
b.name = 'bar' // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property
```

What if I want to create a 'name' property for b while keeping a untouched.
Is it possible? If not, could you tell me why it doesn't work.
Can someone help me out, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the replies from @Satpal. But what still making me confused is why Object.defineProperties() can work it around while b.name can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `name` property while creating `b` object.

```js
"use strict";
var a = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  name: {
    writable: false,
    value: 'foo'
  }
});

var b = Object.create(a, {
  name: {
    value: 'bar',
    writable: false
  }
});

console.log(a.name, b.name)
```

---

You can also use [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) method defines new or modifies existing properties directly on an object.

```js
"use strict";
var a = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    name: {
        writable: false,
        value: 'foo'
    }
});

var b = Object.create(a);
Object.defineProperties(b, {
  name: {
    value: 'bar',
    writable: false
  }
});

console.log(a.name, b.name)
```

Comment: Or `Object.defineProperty` (singular), as there's only the one property to define.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but could you explain why "b.name = 'bar'" causes the error. In my opinion, b looks for property name -> no -> ask for a -> yes -> change to 'bar' -> error(writable is false), this can explain. But that flow can't explain when a.name's writable is true. b.name will have its own name property.

Comment: @biao As `b` is created using `a` it(`b`) inherits properties from `a`.`"b.name = 'bar'"` throws error as `name` property is inherited from object `a` hence not `writable`

Comment: Using`var b = Object.create(a);`, **b itself has no `name` property**, as you can verify with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(b, 'name') // undefined`.

Comment: @biao, Its true. Since you are creating object using prototyping. `name` is inherited see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/nnkLzdem/)  and also see [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to redefine the `name` property of `b` to be `writable`.

```
"use strict";
var a = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    name: {
        writable: false,
        value: 'foo'
    }
});

var b = Object.create(a, {
    name: {
        writable: true,
        value: a.name
    }
});
b.name = 'bar';
```

Alternatively, make `name` an `enumerable` property and create `b` using `Object.assign`.

```
"use strict";
var a = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    name: {
        enumerable: true,
        writable: false,
        value: 'foo'
    }
});

var b = Object.assign({}, a);
b.name = 'bar';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but could you explain why "b.name = 'bar'" causes the error. In my opinion, b looks for property name -> no -> ask for a -> yes -> change to 'bar' -> error(writable is false), this can explain. But that flow can't explain when a.name's writable is true. b.name will have its own name property.

Comment: The configuration for `b.name` is inherited from `a`. If `a.name` is writable, `b.name` is also writable. If `a.name` is not writable, `b.name` is also not writable.

Comment: when b is created with `b = Object.create(a)`, **b has no name property**